# add parameters / query string values in action filter. c# mvc3

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

When I attempt to add either parameters or query string values to the context inside an action filter, an exception gets raised to say that the collection is read only.

I would like to add values to the 'outgoing' url when it is created.

```
filterContext.ActionParameters.Add("test", "test");
```

I need these values passed on to the query string, or in the request parameters.
Thanks

Comment: these collections reflect the incoming request and can not be changed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

HttpContext.Request.Params is read only. It's reflects the incoming request.

Consider using [HttpContext.Items](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.items.aspx) to save our own objects/values

```
filterContext.HttpContext.Items.Add("test","test")
```